# Custom XML RSs feed

Tags: php, xml, rss, mysqli

for the past 6 weeks I have been developing a custom social network in php and mysqli. Anyway today I decided to create a feed for the blogging system. I have checked my script with the w3 feed validation service and it works fine!
The problem is that none of the feeds are showing up on the page, here is my script.....>

```
<?php include"php_includes/db_conx.php"; ?>
<?php header('Content-type: text/xml'); ?>
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>';
?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
<title>Birdbooks Blog Feed</title>
<description>Birdbook is a Social Network with Birders in mind</description>
<link>http://www.birdbook.org.uk/</link> <copyright> copyright 2013 Birdbook Social Network</copyright>
<atom:link href="http://www.birdbook.org.uk/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
<?php $query = "SELECT * FROM 'blog' ORDER BY 'delimiter' DESC LIMIT 0,15";
$results = $db_conx->query($query);
$number = $results->num_rows;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++) {
    $row = $results->fetch_assoc();
    $title = $row['blogtitle'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $link = $row['linklabel'];
    $date = date("r", $row['lastmodified']);
?>
<item>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<description><?php echo $description; ?></description>
<link><?php echo $link; ?></link>
<pubDate><?php echo $date; ?></pubDate>
<guid><?php echo $link; ?></guid>
</item>
<?php } ?>
</channel>
</rss><?php $db->close(); ?>
```

Anyone got any Ideas?
Many thanks.. Phillip Dews

Comment: FYI, you should create the XML with something like http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php or DOMDocument

Comment: The outputted XML would be more useful than the script itself I guess, if there are no PHP errors.

Comment: what does it mean `"none of the feeds are showing up on the page"`? What did you do to show? How we expected to know what is the page you're talking about?